# Should i do NAT myself in establishing web RTC connection between two browsers over different network on internet?

Tags: web, webrtc

I have implemented webRTC peer to peer connection and the code works fine in my local network . I have taken video stream and injected the stream over RTCPeer connection . It is showing the video of the remote host . SSL certificate is valid now before on my xampp it was being the issue and i hosted the js script on live website with ssl configured and i tested again but i am not able to see the remote host video and not getting any error over console . 
My question here is should i do NAT explicitly for webRTC code to work over internet or WebRTC does that for me.